# Issues setting a maximum amount of tokens in ERC20 contract

Tags: token, ethereum, solidity, erc20

I've been trying to create a very simple ERC20 token with truffle in the rinkeby network. I placed the following code into my .sol file but the max supply doesnt seem to match.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract Artytoken is ERC20 {

    address public admin;
    uint private _totalSupply;

    constructor() ERC20('ArtyToken', 'AATK') {
        admin = msg.sender;
        _totalSupply = 1000000;
        _mint(admin, _totalSupply);
    }
}
```

In my Metamask address shows that i own "0.000000000001" and I've seen that in Etherscan it shows that the max total supply its "0.000000000001". What im doing wrong?
Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The EVM does not support decimal numbers (to prevent rounding errors related to the network nodes running on different architectures), so all numbers are integers.

The [ERC-20](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20) token standard defines the `decimals()` function that your contract [implements](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v4.6.0/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol#L87), effectively shifting all numbers by the declared number of zeros to simulate decimals.

So if you wanted to mint 1 token with 18 decimals, you'd need to pass the value `1000000000000000000` (18 zeros). Or as in your case, 1 million tokens (6 zeros) with 18 decimals is represented as `1000000000000000000000000` (24 zeros). Same goes the other way around, 0.5 of a token with 18 decimals is `500000000000000000` (17 zeros).

You can also use underscores (they effectively do nothing but visually separate the value) and scientific notation to mitigate human error while working with such large amount of zeros:

```
// 6 zeros and 18 zeros => 24 zeros
_totalSupply = 1_000_000 * 1e18;
```